# Should I run a 32Eth Validator or just use a POW Goeth Faucet?

Tags: evm, proof-of-stake, validators, goerli, faucets

I've with patience POW mined 32 Eth from the [Pow Goeth Faucet](https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/) and started a Goerli Validator; My reason? There's a bunch of scammers pieces of :poop: hoarding Testnet Eth and trying to sell it making it really hard to get testnet eth, this makes it hard for me to provide my QA team goeth to test our platform tools.

After developing a while I get this thought:

"If I run a validator I am supporting the network and getting a few testnet eth, I'm also avoiding the risk of burning my 15 years ol' becky(my laptop) minning in the faucet"

however I've seen that minning ETH via Validator is slower than using the POW faucet

Is there any other benefit than the passive GOETH income & having my personal RPC node for running a node?

please help me with thoughts!

Comment: Use other testnetwork like sepolia, mumbai, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://goerlifaucet.com/ with 10 emails, vpn and clear cache. Also I ask my friends to do the same. So I'm getting around 5 eth per day which is alright for me to test. Also mining is good.

Comment: this is a good workaround for the lack of goeth, :C still I think its a bit inconvenient that the faucets are limited due to the hoarders :c